# How to remove querystring when using Umbraco rewrite

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, umbraco, iis-8

I have a rewrite rule as below to my Umbraco/ASP .Net site

```
<add name="Test" virtualUrl="^~/category/(.*)" destinationUrl="/category?cat=$1" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" ignoreCase="true" />
```

The idea is if a user types

```
www.example.com/category/electronics
www.example.com/category/devices
www.example.com/category/food
www.example.com/category/beverages
```

Everything works as i would expect when they reach the page without any rules and plain URLs i.e.

```
www.example.com/category?cat=electronics
```

If i have the above rule it enabled it always adds/forwards the querystring parameter `i.e cat=` when you click a link on any of the pages above.

How could i stop forwarding/adding the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below URL rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="add query string" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^category/([^/]+)/$" />

                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/category?cat={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

if you did not install URL rite module in iis you could install it from the below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @Computer what is your exact requirement could you please explain in detail?

Comment: When i have the above rule enabled and go to (sample link is  www.example.com/category/electronics) the page displays. If i click any link on that page it adds ?catid= to it which i dont want. Removing the rule doesnt have this issue. When i hover over the link on the page ?catid= is not listed though. I also noticed if i change the VirtualUrl to something different the problem doesnt occur

Comment: @Computer could share any sample link which set on that page?

Comment: If i arrive to the page using the friendly link i see the product link as https://www.example.com/electronics/video?pid=1&bid=2 but clicking this link changes the URL to ?cid=video&pid=1&bid=2 - i just need the cid parameter removed

Comment: @Computer my suggested rule does not match if any other things added after the category/electronics/  check this [image](https://imgur.com/a/F9FMGjd)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215642/discussion-between-computer-and-jalpa-panchal).

Comment: @Computer you could try this `<rule name="add query string" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^category/([^/]+)/$" />

<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/category?cid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>`